# how to deleted an item with the same `x` and `y` but different key and also adds all the `g` with the same 'x' and 'y'

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I have an array of objects:

```
let input = [
  { key: 0, x: 0, y: 0, g: 1 },
  { key: 1, x: 0, y: 0, g: 2 },
  { key: 2, x: 2, y: 0, g: 3 },
  { key: 3, x: 0, y: 0, g: 3 },
  { key: 4, x: 2, y: 2, g: 1 },
  { key: 5, x: 2, y: 2, g: 2 },
];
```

I mean I want to remove duplicate objects with the same x and y, and convert All of them to one, and also I want to add all the `g` which has same  `x` and `y`. and I would like to sort them with the new `key` value.

```
let result = [
  { key: 0, x: 0, y: 0, g: 6 },
  { key: 1, x: 2, y: 0, g: 3 },
  { key: 2, x: 0, y: 0, g: 3 },
];
```

is it possible to help me.

I try by myself to remove but it doesn't work properly

```
    const set = new Set(json1.map((item) => JSON.stringify(item)));
    const uniq = [...set].map((item) => JSON.parse(item));
console.log(uniq)
```

Comment: Why this `{"key":0"x":0,"y":0,"g":6}` is in output when you want to remove object which has same `x` and `y` value?

Comment: You do not have [JSON](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Objects/JSON) here. You have JavaScript Objects

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be achieved with a standard 'group-by', grouping by a composite key of `x` and `y` and summing `g`.

*(Your stated expected output is not consistent with your description of your problem. And it is unclear if you want to retain the original keys or generate new ones)*

```js
let input = [
  { key: 0, x: 0, y: 0, g: 1 },
  { key: 1, x: 0, y: 0, g: 2 },
  { key: 2, x: 2, y: 0, g: 3 },
  { key: 3, x: 0, y: 0, g: 3 },
  { key: 4, x: 2, y: 2, g: 1 },
  { key: 5, x: 2, y: 2, g: 2 },
];

const result = Object.values(
  input.reduce((a, { key, x, y, g }) => (((a[`x_${x}_y_${y}`] ??= { key, x, y, g: 0 }).g += g), a), {})
);

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```